# Differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x_0 =0$ and $y_0 \in (0, \pi)$

$$y' = \sin(y) \tag 1 $$

and: $$ y' = x \sin(y) \tag 2 $$

The question is to find the solution of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

I have already shown that $\int \frac 1 {\sin(x)} \, dx = \ln|\tan(\frac x 2 )|$

I have  to use the theorem that says , let $\varphi(x)$ the solution of (1) then $ H(\varphi(x)) = F(x) $ 
with $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t) \, dt $

$$ H(y)= \int_{y_0}^y \frac 1 {g(s)} \, ds $$

In my case, it is clear that $g(y) = \sin(y)$ for both $(1)$ and $(2)$

$\textbf{My Try}~(1)$

$$ H(y)= \int_{y_0}^y \frac 1 {g(s)} \, ds = \int_{y_0}^y \frac 1 {\sin(s)} \, ds = \ln\left|\tan\left(\frac y 2\right)\right| - \ln \left|\tan\left(\frac{y_0}2\right)\right|$$

$$F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t) \, dt = \int_{x_0}^x 1 \, dt  = x-x_0= x$$

Now I must search for the inverse function of $H$:

$$ H^{-1} : H(D) \to  D $$

$$H(y) =w \Rightarrow \ln\left|\tan \left(\frac y 2 \right)\right| - \ln\left|\tan\left( \frac{y_0}2 \right)\right| = w$$

$$\ln\left|\tan \left( \frac y 2 \right)\right| = w + \ln\left|\tan\left( \frac {y_0} 2 \right)\right|$$

$$\left|\tan \left(\frac y 2 \right)\right| = \exp \left(w+\ln\left|\tan \left( \frac{y_0} 2 \right) \right|\right)$$

$$\tan\left(\frac y 2\right) = \exp\left(w+\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{y_0} 2 \right) \right)\right) \text{ because } y \in (0,\pi)$$

$$ y = 2\tan^{-1} \left(\exp\left(w+\ln\left(\tan\left( \frac{y_0} 2 \right) \right) \right) \right)$$

$$H^{-1}(w) =2\tan^{-1}\left(\exp\left(w+\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{y_0} 2\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

$$ H(\varphi(x)) = F(x) \Rightarrow \varphi(x)= H^{-1}(F(x))$$

$$\varphi(x)= 2\tan^{-1}\left(\exp\left(x+\ln\left(\tan\left( \frac{y_0} 2 \right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: find the  solution of  $\varphi'(x) =f(x)*g(\varphi(x))$

Comment: You should use $\exp(w+\ln(u))=e^w·u$ to somewhat simplifiy the expressions. Everything else looks good.